# How to import images/change them on button click? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, photo

I am trying to import images from a folder on my server strictly using JavaScript so that I can switch it out with a new image on button click. I know how to import photos using HTML, but is there a way to do it through JavaScript? What is the best way to do this? Any help, guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed an image within a dom element on your page.  Here is a really simple example html file which does this assuming the `myimage.jpg` file is in the same directory.  Check out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) for more info on javascript.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function btnClick()
    {
        spanElement = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
        spanElement.innerHTML = '<img src="myimage.jpg" />';
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="btnClick()">Show Image</button>
        <span id="imgContainer"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that did not work....all my pictures are in a folder named Cat_Pictures, but my html files are in the root of my server

Comment: Assuming that you have uploaded the folder to your server folder, then you can reference each picture like '/Cat_Pictures/myimage.jpg'.  Again, here is a good w3schools example of referencing images from various locations: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_diffloc